# phpDocumentor - "Is phpdoc in either the path or include_path in your php.ini file?"

Tags: environment-variables, php, phpdoc

I'm trying to run phpDocumentor and am getting this error... I've searched extensively on Google and cannot find a solution that works, unfortunately I couldn't install via PEAR so I've had to download from their github and try to do things manually.

I have set the *environmental variables* as appropriate:

```
C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor;C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\bin;
```

And the include_path within *php.ini* too:

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor;C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\bin;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

I'm trying to generate docs by using the following code: `phpdoc -d Z: -t Z:\docs\phpDoc`

But then I get the following error:

> Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini...    (found in
>   C:\php\pear\data/PhpDocumentor/)... ERROR: cannot open
>   phpDocumentor.ini in directory C:/xampp/php/pear/PhpDocumentor
>   -Is phpdoc in either the path or include_path in your php.ini file?

I'm stumped by this, would really appreciate any advice on getting this working, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini... (found in C:\php\pear\data/PhpDocumentor/)... ERROR: cannot open phpDocumentor.ini in directory C:/xampp/php/pear/PhpDocumentor -Is phpdoc in either the path or include_path in your php.ini file?

Error is cause of phpdoc.bat settings. Simple solutions is copy folder C:/xampp/php/pear/PhpDocumentor to C:\php\pear\data\ place or you can set your path with in phpdoc.bat file. Check if you have no any phpDocumentor.ini file then create or download from internet.

Answer (score 1):

The "found in C:\php\pear\data/PhpDocumentor" piece of the error makes me wonder if you have things installed in C:\php\ or in C:\xampp\php.  Might the phpDocumentor.ini file be in C:\php\ instead of C:\xampp\php\ ?

As an aside, you probably don't need "C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor" in your $PATH... just its /bin subdirectory in order to have the "phpdoc" executable available to your command line prompt.