# PHP Documentor Error

Tags: php

Ihave installed php documentor using pear using commands

---

`$ pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org`

---

`$ pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor`

```
Error: failed to mkdir c:/php/pear/data/phpDocumentor/features/generates-documentation/create-documents-using-twigs
```

---

and now I am writing
`$ phpdoc run -d E:/input/demo.php -t E:/output` then the error comes as follows

```
Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini...
<found in c:\php\pear\data/phpDocumentor/>
Error: cannot open phpDocumentor.ini in directory c:/xampp/php/pear/phpDocumentor
-Is phpdoc in either the path or include_path in your php.ini file?
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Does the ini file exist? If not, did you try to create it?

Comment: try this answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12095711/568651

Comment: Tried now sir..still no result.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same trouble and solved it.
My xampp already installed phpDocumentor 1.x. So I need to uninstall it.

1. upgrade pear

   > pear upgrade PEAR
2. check phpDocumentor version

   > pear list
3. uninstall phpDocumentor 1.x

   > pear uninstall PhpDocumentor
4. install phpDocumentor 2.x

   > pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
   >   pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old but it may be off use to someone else.
You must change the pear config.

First:

```
C:\path-to-xampp-php-pear\>pear config-show
```

Verify the config and change it according to your path.
In my case the problem was when the config was set for **c:\php\pear** instead of **c:\xampp\php\pear**

To change it execute:
`pear config-set doc_dir c:\xampp\php\pear\docs`

Comment: I needed both this solution from @Adrian (but I changed ALL paths that were not pointed at the c:\xampp\php\peardirectory) - and also the upgrade pear, uninstall / reinstall phpDocumentor from Kiyoshi, to make mine work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your php is inside your **/xampp/** folder and pear tries to access it via fallowing path: **c:/php/pear/data/...**

It is just workaround, but you can just copy a dummy **c:/xampp/php/pear/** folder from xampp to your C: drive...